# Picking up one record from MYSQL based on two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables:

**order** with row `ID` and `ID_CLIENT`

and

**user** with row `ID`, `FIRSTNAME`, `SURNAME`, `PHONE` etc.

**My problem is:**

I want to see `order details` like `names, phone number` on page to exactly client `id` of order I'm looking at.

**Tried this:**

```
SELECT name FROM client,order WHERE order.id_client=client.id
```

but it came up with more than one name that should came with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is not complete.

```
SELECT name FROM client,order WHERE order.id_client=client.id AND client.id=999
```

Change `999` to your client id.